# PHPUnit is returning 404 when it should be 200

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I've never written test cases before and am attempting to do this for an API I have written.

I'm trying to call a route with a post request and so am using the below:

```
public function testRequestCorrectApiKey()
    {
        //Request with X-Authorization sending correct API Key
        $response = $this->call('POST', '/authenticate', ['email' => 'testingphpunit@phpunittest.com', 'password' => 'phpunittest', [], [], ['X-Authorization' => '123workingapikey123']]);

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
    }
```

This is always failing with the error:

> Failed asserting that 404 matches 200

This would naturally indicate that it is sending the request to the wrong path. How can I ensure it is being posted to the correct URL and how can I see what it is trying to reach?

I've tried updating the APP url in my `.env` file to `http://localhost/gm-api/public` and in my `config/app.php` file too.

I have also updated the stock `TestCase.php` with:

```
protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/gm-api/public';
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: step through with a debugger?

Comment: @Gordon how do I do that when I am running phpunit from the command line?

Comment: There u go: http://blog.doh.ms/2011/05/13/debugging-phpunit-tests-in-netbeans-with-xdebug/

It'll be very useful when the actual code works but your unit tests fail and you start questioning your own existence ;)

Comment: Are you sure it should be hitting `public` in the url?

Comment: Did `protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';` not work for you?

Comment: @haakym yes public should be in the URL - I have tested it in POSTMAN and it works for me just fine. and no updating the `baseUrl` did not change anything for me.

Comment: @haakym I've tried getting xdebug to work. I have installed it in to sublime and set a breakpoint at the `call()` but I can't get it working. Is there anyway to get PHPUnit to output the url it is calling?

Comment: @James Testing in POSTMAN and phpunit are not the same thing, you don't need your dev server running for phpunit to work. AFAIK phpunit runs its own server, hence why I asked regarding the base url. So could you confirm that using `protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';` works/doesn't work by using a very simple test, perhaps try using something similar to the default test that comes with URL `$this->visit('/')->see('My App')` then if that's working move on to testing the API with authentication etc.

Comment: Try `var_dump` or `dd()` in your testing code and you should see it in the console when running phpunit, actually I just tested this myself with `vardump('hi')` and it works okay for me, I can see it in the console.

Comment: @haakym I'll try it when I get home, can you use `var_dump` to print out the URL in anyway? I can't see how it would as `$this->call()` executes the request... Anyway I'll give it a crack when I'm home, just wanted to see if you knew.

Comment: Running xdebug may not yield the same results as running phpunit as xdebug would be running on your local dev server whereas phpunit is running your tests on its own server

Comment: Pretty sure it would be `$baseUrl` + the second parameter in the call method. `$this->call()` returns Illuminate\Http\Response https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Response.html so there may be a way to inspect that for the URL if it exists there (I'm not sure that it does). Hope you can work it out.

Comment: you have created any middleware?

Comment: @RaghavRangani I have, but it is just checking for the presence of the `X-Authorization` header, and if it isn't there it should just return a 401 status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this, and personally think this is a better way to do it, by simply using Guzzle to run the tests.

```
/**
 * Send a request with the correct API Key
*/
public function testRequestCorrectApiKey()
{
    $key = ApiKey::find(1);

    //Request with X-Authorization sending correct API Key
    $path = 'authenticate';
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/gm-api/public/')]);
    $response = $client->request("POST", $path, ["email" => "testingphpunit@phpunittest.com", "password" => "phpunittest", "headers" => ["X-Authorization" => $key->key ]]);
    $status_code = $response->getStatusCode();

    $this->assertEquals(200, $status_code);
}
```

The benefit of this, is you can just set the Base URL inside the `.env` file with `APP_URL` and it is good to go.

I'm unsure why I couldn't get `$this->call()` to work after changing the `$baseUrl` in the default test case - I can only assume it was still hitting the wrong URL. However, using Guzzle has solved this for me and is actually testing the configuration of the server too - given PHPUnit spins up its own version, yet this is testing the current server environment.